# Using reflection to get properties of an instance of a class at runtime C#

Tags: c#, reflection

Hi here is what I am trying to do, I have a class (EventType) which can be dynamic and have different members/properties at different times.

```
class EventType
{
    int id{set;}
    string name{set;}
    DateTime date{set;}
    List<int> list{set;}
    Guid guid{set;}
}
```

In my main method I am passing an instance on this class to a to a function in a different class and trying reflection to get the properties of the instance but its not successful and giving me null value.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EventType event1 = new EventType();
        int rate = 100;
        DataGenerator.Generate<EventType>(event1, rate);
    }
    public static byte[] test(EventType newEvent)
    {
        return new byte[1];
    }
}



static class DataGenerator
{
    public static void Generate<T>(T input, int eventRate, Func<T, byte[]> serializer=null)
    {            
        Type t = input.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(property.ToString());   
        }
        var bytes = serializer(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding your "Generate" method, I'm wondering what is different from  out-of-the-box serialization? (Binary serialization, xml serialization or JSon). Shouldn't you rely on existing serialization mechanisms?

Comment: I am trying to make the method such that people can use their own serializers, if they don't provide one the I will go ahead and use one of the existing one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class properties are private by default, and `GetProperties` only return public properties.

Either promote your properties as public :

```
class EventType
{
    public int id{set;}
    public string name{set;}
    public DateTime date{set;}
    public List<int> list{set;}
    public Guid guid{set;}
}
```

Or specify binding flas to get non-public properties :

```
Type t = input.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | // Include protected and private properties
    BindingFlags.Public | // Also include public properties
    BindingFlags.Instance // Specify to retrieve non static properties
    );
```

Comment: @peter Thanks for the help what will be the case if I used fields instead of properties? `code` class EventType
    {
        int id;
        string name;
        DateTime date;
        List<int> list;
        Guid guid;
    } `code`

Comment: Replace `GetProperties` by [`GetFields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[Type.GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the **public** properties of a type. But since you haven't specified whether the access type of your properties they are **private**.

You can use the overloaded [Type.GetProperties(BindingFlags)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) method to get all properties, regardless of their access modifier.

Answer (score 2):

[`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx) returns all *public* properties, in your class they are all private so they won't be returned. You can either make them public or use [`BindingFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) to search for private ones also, eg:

```
t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class EventType
{
    int id { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
    DateTime date { get;  set; }
    List<int> list { get; set; }
    Guid guid { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EventType event1 = new EventType();
        int rate = 100;
        DataGenerator.Generate<EventType>(event1, rate);
    }
    public static byte[] test(EventType newEvent)
    {
        return new byte[1];
    }
}



static class DataGenerator
{
    public static void Generate<T>(T input, int eventRate, Func<T, byte[]> serializer = null)
    {
        Type t = input.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(property.ToString());
        }
        //var bytes = serializer(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: `code` Thanks for the help what will be the case if I used fields instead of properties?class EventType
    {
        int id;
        string name;
        DateTime date;
        List<int> list;
        Guid guid;
    } `code`